# JavaScript Object.values from an array of object

Tags: javascript

Here is my object:

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'Breaking Bad S01E07' },
  { name: 'Breaking Bad S01E06' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E05' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E02' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E07' },
];
```

I want to extract just values and I used Object.values but it don't change.

Here is my code:

```
val = Object.values(arr);
console.log(val);
```

But what I get is exactly the same without Object.values. It doesn't return values. I returns keys + values.

I used map on it cuz it is an array of objects but it returns undefined!

```
const map = arr.map((x) => {
  Object.values(x);
});
console.log(map);
```

here is what I get:

```
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Comment: The values of an array are the array elements.

Comment: Your function in the `map()` isn't returning anything. Try `return Object.values(x);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to map and then destructure the `name` from each object.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'Breaking Bad S01E07' },
  { name: 'Breaking Bad S01E06' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E05' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E02' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E07' },
];

const values = arr.map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(values);
```

If you want all the values without their keys, you could try reducing the values.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'Breaking Bad S01E07' },
  { name: 'Breaking Bad S01E06' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E05' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E02' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E07' },
];

const values = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => [...acc, ...Object.values(obj)], []);

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

The map function should always return a value.
You can change your map function in this way.

```
const map = arr.map((x) => Object.values(x));
console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from `map` callback function, hence, it populates the resultant array with `undefined`

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'Breaking Bad S01E07' },
  { name: 'Breaking Bad S01E06' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E05' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E02' },
  { name: 'Dexter S01E07' },
];

// Using object.values

const val = arr.map(item => Object.values(item)[0]);

// OR Accessing value directly
const values = arr.map(item => item.name)


console.log(values, val);
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback function in `map()` needs to return something.

```
const map = arr.map((x) => {
  return Object.values(x);
});
```

Or you can use the shorthand format that automatically returns an expression by leaving out the `{}` around the body:

```
const map = arr.map((x) => Object.values(x));
```